# Why does the WebhookResponse builder create wrong key in json?

Tags: java, kotlin, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to utilise `com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.WebhookResponse` to interact with my dialogflow agent. But I'm having trouble responding back to the agent during fulfillment.

The response created doesn't follow the specifications required i.e the agent expect the json to be `fulfillmentText: "something"` but the builder builds it in the format of `fulfillment_text`. There's not enough documentation on how to use API client correctly

Anyone has experience doing this in java/kotlin?

```
val response = WebhookResponse
                .newBuilder()
                .setFulfillmentText("Hello")
                .build()

println(response)
println(Gson().toJson(response))
```

Output:

> fulfillment_text: "Hello"
>
> {"bitField0_":0,"fulfillmentText_":"Hello","fulfillmentMessages_":
>   [],"source_":"","outputContexts_":[],"memoizedIsInitialized":1,"unknownFields":{"fields":{}},"memoizedSize":-1,"memoizedHashCode":0}

I'm using `'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.75.1-alpha'` from https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/libraries/java

Comment: Can you update your question to indicate (and possibly provide a link to) which library you're using?

Comment: @Prisoner updated the library / link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you're using is primarily designed as a [client library](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#detect_intent_and_agent_apis), letting you send text to Dialogflow and having it determine the Intent and parameters (and possibly a response) from that text.

It sounds like you're trying to use this on the other end - in a webhook to handle [fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#fulfillment). It just isn't designed for that. The Class was automatically generated from the [ProtoBuf definition](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/675ace7601e2c09474ce986d5d2223af5cb15f28/google-api-grpc/proto-google-cloud-dialogflow-v2/src/main/proto/google/cloud/dialogflow/v2/webhook.proto), which does not serialize to JSON, and isn't designed to represent things that way.

You will need to build the JSON for the response yourself.